# Zappa Django one lambda per app in a monorepo

Tags: python, django, zappa

My Django REST API is composed of multiples apps, one app per resource like that:

```
├── core
│   ├── settings.py
│   ├── urls.py
├── customers
│   ├── models.py
│   ├── serializers.py
│   ├── urls.py
│   └── views.py
├── orders
│   ├── models.py
│   ├── serializers.py
│   ├── urls.py
│   └── views.py
```

The settings of the app are all in core/settings.py.

How can I tell zappa to deploy each app in a different lambda function and configure API Gateway to handle the routing for each app?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest you add a **stage** per app in your `zappa_settings.json` file.  Then you can deploy each **stage** independently.

See [the documentation](https://github.com/zappa/Zappa#installation-and-configuration) for exact formatting.

Comment: As my settings are all in the core app, should I create a "dummy" settings file for each app to be able to configure the Zappa app: "django_settings": "your_project.settings" ?

Comment: If each app behaves differently, then yes - you'd probably want different settings files for each app.  But not, then the Django settings for the core app should be the one listed in the `zappa_settings.json` file